# Error : unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: objective-c, class, interface

I am a complete noob when it comes to Objective C (or even for OOP for that matter). Here is what I am trying to do

### AInterface.m

```
@implementation AInterface

 - (BOOL)getParam:(NSData **)a param1:(NSData**)param1 param2:(NSData**)param2
{

       //Do a bunch of things
       return bool;
} 

@end
```

### AInterface.h

```
@interface AInterface : NSObject

- (BOOL)getParam:(NSData **)a param1:(NSData**)param1 param2:(NSData**)param2;

+ (instancetype) inst;
@end
```

### testMain.m()

```
int main()
{
    Bool result = NO;
    NSData *a = Nil;
    NSData *b = Nil;
    NSData *c = Nil;

    result = [[AInterface inst] getParam:(NSData **)&a param1:(NSData**)&a param2:(NSData**)&b];

    return result 
}
```

When I run this though, I get an error saying failed:

```
 caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "+[AInterface inst]: unrecognized selector sent to class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you declared +inst method in @interface section your class does not have it implemented and that leads to runtime error. You need to add implementation to make it work, e.g.

```
@implementation AInterface
...
+ (instancetype)inst {
   return [self new];
}
```

Comment: Why should I have an instance method at all? Is it possible to call the method without an instance? If yes, what would it look like?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Just declare your methods as class (using `+`) and call it: +(BOOL)getParam:(NSData **)a ... and then [AInterface getParam:...]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was trying to do! I just didn't fully understand what I had to look for. This is very helpful Thank you!

Comment: It's a bad, bad idea to make all of the methods as class methods. Most should be instance methods. Most classes have state and that requires an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't have implementation of `+inst` in `AInterface.m`.
In your case `inst` would be something like: 
`[[AInterface alloc] init]` but I'd just use `[[AInterface alloc] init]` instead of calling `inst` in the first place. Or `[AInterface new]`, which stands for the same.

In general, the rest of your code is not idiomatic Objective-C.

Comment: what do you mean by not idiomatic Objective-C? (English isn't my first language)

Comment: It means that the general approach to how you design the API for your classes and how your code looks is not the usual way Objective-C is written. It looks like you're trying to write Objective-C but think in C++ or Java or some other language. For example, you almost never see methods like get... in Objective-C. And instead of `Nil`, `nil` should be used. And `BOOL` instead of `Bool`.